# How can I read an updated book version on Amazon Cloud Reader using Firefox?

Tags: firefox, amazon, kindle

I got an email that an e-book I purchased from Amazon was updated. I logged on to Amazon, found the book in my Kindle library, and clicked the link to update the book. I figured out how to update the copy on my Kindle and the copy on my Kindle for PC, but I cannot seem to figure out how to update the book on my Amazon Cloud Reader. I tried clicking Actions... then Deliver to my.. then Deliver to: Ben's Kindle Cloud Reader, but the copy of the book is still not updated.

How can I update my book on Amazon Cloud Reader? I have been using Firefox (currently 14.0) to read ebooks on [Amazon Cloud Reader](https://read.amazon.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon Cloud Reader is not updating the book because it is being cached by Firefox. Clearing the cache will force Firefox to redownload the book.

First, in Firefox select Options.

[image: Firefox Options screenshot]

Then under the Advanced > Network tab, there is a section for Offline Web Content and User Data. You should see read.amazon.com in the list of websites allowed to store data for offline use. Simply click Clear Now and the next time you open the book in Amazon Cloud Reader, it will be updated.

If you have already located the book on the Manage Your Kindle page, you can select Actions... then Deliver to my... and then Deliver to: Ben's Kindle Cloud Reader and then click Deliver to open a tab with the updated book using Amazon Cloud Reader.

[image: Manage Your Kindle link]

[image: Deliver to my... popup]